# D3500 withAF Nikkor 50 mm F/1.8 D incompatible lens

Tags: lens

can soneone please give me an idiots guide to how to load this lens and get ot working on my D3500.

Ive set the apature to 22 and locked it but when I try to take a picture its just black.

I cant change the apature or shutter or anything and I just get F-- in the appature section and "incompatible lens flashing up

Comment: See also: [Why is my Nikon 50mm f/1.8 giving me an fEE error?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/8343) and [What is the difference between Nikkor D type and G type lenses?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/45814)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use this lens as an automatic lens on a D3500.

The Nikkor 50mm f1.8 **D** lenses require a specific version of the Nikon F mount that is not implemented fully on the D3500.

To autofocus it requires a camera with a lens motor in the body, which the D3500 does not have.  You require Nikon lenses marked as "G AF-S" or third party lenses with focus motors in the lens itself for full automatic operation.  The Nikon G AF-P lenses also apparently work fully.

According to the manual for the D3500 (always a good place to start !) **D** type lenses can only be used in **M** mode - that is using full manual exposure - no automatic controls at all.

Comment: You may be able to get the focus confirmation dot, if the aperture is wide enough [I can on my D5500] but as you say, no auto-focus & also no light meter, as it can't read the aperture. AF-S are also a bit restricted on D3xxx if the lens has an aperture ring [it can't read it]. If you want to play safe, always look for G or AF-P.

Comment: Do you have any idea why auto exposure does not work on that camera? If it can't read the aperture, then how can it set it?

Comment: @Orbit The lens was designed for a version of F mount long before the D3500.  The D3500 (like all entry level Nikon DSLRs after the D50) does not support the method used by D lenses for autoexposure information or setting aperture.  To set aperture you use the (physical) aperture ring on the lens - that is, you set aperture manually.  The D lens will work on some "higher" models of DSLR that support the mechanism it uses.

Comment: Note that not all D lenses are AF, though the vast majority are. There are several AF-S D lenses. There may also be some G lenses that are not AF-S or AF-P. One refers to how the aperture communicates with the camera, the other refers to whether there is an AF motor in the lens or if there needs to be an AF motor in the body.